# Problema con matrices en Java

Tags: java, matrices

buenas tengo la siguiente pregunta/duda...

este código lo que hace es dado un arreglo multiplicar sus elementos por un entero y devolverlo

```java
static int[] multiplicarArray(int[] arr, int k) {
    int[] nuevo = new int[arr.length];
    for(int i = 0;i < arr.length; i++) {
        nuevo[i] = arr[i] * k;
    }
    return nuevo;
}
```

lo que quisiera es que dado una matriz fijarme si una de sus columnas es el arreglo multiplicado, pero no me estaría funcionando (se que el código a continuación esta mal pero no estaría encontrando la solución)

```java
static boolean existeColumnaMultiplol(int[][] mat, int[] vec, int k) {
    boolean res = false;
    int[] nuevo = multiplicarArray(vec, k);
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.length; i++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < mat[0].length; c++) {
            for (int f = 0; f < mat.length; f++)
            res = res || (mat[f][c] == nuevo[i]);
        }

    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno a ver que te parece, lo hice con el siguiente método, va comparando los números de la primera columna hasta abajo y luego la segunda y así...

```
public static boolean existeColumnaMultiploK(int[][] bidiArray, int[] array, int k) {
    int[] nuevo = multiplicarArray(array, k);
    int contador = 0;
        
    for (int x = 0; x < bidiArray[0].length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < bidiArray.length; y++) {
            if(contador == array.length) 
                return true;
                
            if(nuevo[y] == bidiArray[y][x]) 
                contador++;
                
            else 
                contador = 0;
        }   
    }
        
    return (contador == array.length);
}
```

Y el código completo seria algo así

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[]{1,2,3};
        
    int[][] bidiArray = {{10,2,5}, // Es la segunda columna.
                         {5,4,9},
                         {0,6,4}};
    
    System.out.println(existeColumnaMultiploK(bidiArray, array, 2));
}
    
public static int[] multiplicarArray(int[] array, int k) {
    int[] nuevo = new int[array.length];
        
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        nuevo[i] = array[i] * k;
        
    return nuevo;
}

public static boolean existeColumnaMultiploK(int[][] bidiArray, int[] array, int k) {
    int[] nuevo = multiplicarArray(array, k);
    int contador = 0;
        
    for (int x = 0; x < bidiArray[0].length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < bidiArray.length; y++) {
            if(contador == array.length) 
                return true;
                
            if(nuevo[y] == bidiArray[y][x]) 
                contador++;
                
            else 
                contador = 0;
        }   
    }
        
    return (contador == array.length);
}
```

La variable contador va aumentando a medida que coincida con el nuevo array, al final se hace una comparación, si el contador es igual a array.length, lo que significa que todos los números que hay en esa columna coinciden con los del array multiplicado (en si tienen la misma capacidad, array.length y nuevo.length)